# How to print as a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the following output as a list like this 
eg:
`1,2,3`

my code is

```
import random
list = 0
while list < 3:
        n = random.randint(1,10)
        print(n)
        list = list + 1
```

but my output is rather like this

```
1
2
3
```

what is the simplest way to print it as a comma separated list? if you could explain to me the reasoning behind the solution, that would be great too. thanks!

Comment: `print(','.join(str(random.randint(1,10)) for _ in range(3)))`

Comment: `print(*[random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(3)], sep=', ')`

Comment: As an aside, don't use the name `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code with explanation in the comment:

```
import random
# We create a list l to store the number
l = []

# The while loop ends when the size of l is more than 3
while len(l) < 3:
        n = random.randint(1,10)
        # Append the random number n into l
        l.append(n)
# Print the list l
print(l)
```

Comment: You don't even need a loop if you really just want to print a list literal. `print([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(3)])`.

Comment: @chepner yes, I agree that we can use list comprehension here and it would reduce the number of lines by a lot :) But I think it will be more difficult to explain it

Comment: I would have suggested the list comprehension in the first place if I'd know the OP would accept `[1,2,3]` as output rather than `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your loop is not amenable to replacing it with a generator expression (as in the comments), use `end=','`.

```
import random
list = 0
while list < 3:
        n = random.randint(1,10)
        end = ',' if list < 2 else ''
        print(n, end=end)
        list = list + 1
print()
```

The need to detect the last iteration of the loop, to alter the ending to avoid a trailing comma, makes this less desirable.